# Reading CSV in Python and Outputting Specific Data

Tags: python, windows, csv, output

I am working on a python script that reads user input and returns values from the CSV. I am able to return all values, but I only need a few. There are many columns in the CSV, examples are:

LOC_NBR  LOC_NAME  ALPHA_CODE   FRANCHISE_TYPE  FRANCHISEE_LAST_NAME

My code is below, what could I add to this to only pull the data for say LOC_NBR, LOC_NAME, and FRANCHISE_TYPE? Right now if I change the print statement, I get a data type error because the fields are STR in the csv.

```
import csv

store_Num = input("Enter 5-Digit Store Number: ")
    
with open('StoreDirectory.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    found = False
    
    for line in reader:
            if line[0] == store_Num:
                    print(line)
                    found = True
                    break
    if not found:
            print(store_Num, "not found")
```

Comment: 1) Does the CSV file have the field names as a header? 2) From here [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) look at `csv.DictReader()`. If the file has a header then you do something like `line["LOC_NBR"]`.

Comment: I believe it has headers, but I'm not 100% sure how to check. There are names in the first row of the CSV when opening in excel. I made the suggested change and got

Enter 5-Digit Store Number: 10009
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxx", line 12, in <module>
    if line[0] == store_Num:
KeyError: 0

Comment: I think I might have gotten this to work, will update after testing

Comment: This is now working. Thank you so much for the idea. I hace to change

if line["LOC_NBR"] == store_Num
and
print (line["LOC_NBR']....etc

Answer (score 1):

Using Python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv):

```
cat csv_test.csv 
first,second
1, 1
3, 4

import csv

with open("csv_test.csv") as csv_file:
    c = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in c:
        if int(row["first"]) == 3:
            print(row["first"], row["second"])

3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest (or most convenient) way to do this might be to use the `pandas` module and import the data into a dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

from here you can extract rows or columns as you like.

```
column = "column_name"
row = 2
print ( df[column][row] )
```

Ideally the dataframe needs column headers which will make life easy.

Comment: So you  import a large module that creates a 'fat' object(df) to do the same thing that `csv.DictReader()` does?

Comment: for simplicity and convenience, yes. The entire data is read into the dataframe in one go, even if it is small data, so no need to readlines...

Comment: I've tried to use import pandas, but I can never get it to run correctly. I'm assuming something needs to be installed? I'm on a work PC so maybe not possible?

Comment: all that is required:   `pip install pandas`. . . . . Both `pandas` and `numpy` are the first two modules that i install when using python:   https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html

Comment: @SpencerGray, you don't need to install `pandas` to do what you want. You can make it work without using `pandas` using the the supplied global module `csv`. One less layer of complexity.